# application run method "error application-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run a sub for access using the `Access.application.run` method. It keeps on bringing up error:

> 40351 "error application-defined or object-defined error"

The code is very basic:

```
Dim objAccess, wsh As Object

Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

With objAccess
.OpenCurrentDatabase ("c:\coxi\Documents\Personnal\investment\5334_2.accdb")
.Run "test"    
Set .CurrentProject = Nothing
End With
```

the routine errors on the `.run` line

Comment: is "test" correct?

Comment: yes, "test" is the name of a dummy sub

Comment: Check the macro security settings and add the folder to the list of trusted  locations.

Comment: are you calling a sub called "test" ? if so, surely there should be no quotations?

Comment: @user1 not true. Quotations are required. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-run-method-access

Comment: added the folder and works well now. thanks Kostas

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**: Your code is trying to open un-trusted access DB **"5334_2.accdb"**

**Fix**:

- Open access application
- Goto Trusted center settings under options.
- Add the location of the Access DB file.

Retry executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot !
I had the same hidden problem and could resolve it this way!

I edited code in an .accdb database on the C: drive (C:\…\…\…) and signed the Word templates. Everything worked well, including some Word integration in both directions (Word calling Access procedures and conversely).

When I copied the Access database and the Word templates onto my standard database path (D:\…\…), both the Access database and the Word templates performed well, with the exception of error 40351 in Word on the AccessObj.run "Myproc" …

A pity that neither Word nor Access display a dialog to enable the Access code or at least a sound error message.